# How to insert an hazelcast's ISet into an IMap?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, hazelcast

the tricky part here is, Hazelcast's IMap accepts only serialised object. Unfortunately ISet is not serialisable. So, how to insert ISet into IMap.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, either you use a HashSet inside the IMap (or a customly serialized subclass of a HashSet) or you just use a MultiMap and you have to make sure you won't end up with the same element per key multiple times.

Comment: hey I just tried out multiMap, the documentation promises that it can hold collection as value without serialisation, but i need to configure multiMap. please get me the documentation to configure multimap, so that i can insert ISet into Multimap.